# How to perform 100% accurate OCR in R

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract text from the image [image: Sample input image]

using the code below:

```
txt = ocr("D:/office/ML_PR_1/check.png", engine = tesseract("eng"))

filename = paste("DUMP/OCR", i, ".txt", sep = "")
write(txt, filename)
```

and the output text is:

[image: Output image]

It is observed that OCR is reading B as 3 or 5 and BW as EV.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the Google API for cloud vision,

there is a "RoogleVision" [package](https://github.com/cloudyr/RoogleVision)  to handle the processing

I think you would want to sign up for API key on the Google console!

There is the example console:
[image]

Comment: maybe it would be worth trying it on the OP's example and seeing if it actually does better?

Comment: check the example I added above!

Comment: Hi all Thanks for support I have solved using below code: